# Issue in opening new process window while Executing command in Cmd.Exe using C# Console App

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, console-application, windows-console

I have a below code to execute series of commands in cmd.exe using .Net console.
I have requirement to open new cmd window each time the command executes, so that it can be visualized. 
But below code not opening new window although it executes all commands successfully; I have set window property. Please help.

```
 //Sample Commands
            List<string> mockobject = new List<string>();
            mockobject.Add("type nul >File1.txt");
            mockobject.Add("echo This is a sample text file > File2.txt");
            mockobject.Add("type nul >File3.txt");

            foreach (string _command in mockobject)
            {
                ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + _command);
                procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ProcessDirectory;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                    process.Start();

                    // wait until process does its work
                    process.WaitForExit();

                    // read the result if any
                    if(process.ExitCode != 0)
                    { 
                    string result = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: `ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow` says not to create a new window.

Comment: @CatCat Even if you set it to `false`?

Answer (score 1):

This will open the shell, start your executable and keep the shell window open when the process ends, **notice the /K flag**, you need to include this flag/switch, eg:

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
psi.Arguments = "/K yourmainprocess.exe";
p.Start(psi);
p.WaitForExit();
```

In your code:

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k /c " + _command);
```

Comment: Thank you for suggession. Tried but this did not open new command window while executing.

Comment: So can you please update the question to reflect your new learnings? I thought the aim was to keep the window open, so you can see the results?

Comment: want to open new command window for each command execution and close after execution.